# Is string iteration with single loop is slower compared to iteration of list created from string.split() with multiple loops?

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures, time-complexity

I was working on a simple code problem where I need to Write a function which takes a string as input and prints reversed string in 3 formats as shown below.

```
reverse_str("Hello Folks Lets Code")  --> output as below

edoC steL skloF olleH

Code Lets Folks Hello

olleH skloF steL edoC
```

And I have written below function with a single while loop which only traverse one time through the string and gives the above output. This works perfectly fine.

```
def reverse_str(inp_str: str):
    original_word=''
    reversed_word=''
    order_word_rvrsd=''
    order_rvrsd=''
    word_rvrsd=''
    indx=0
    while True:
        try:
            c=inp_str[indx]
            if c!=' ':
                original_word+=c
                reversed_word=c+reversed_word

            else :
                order_word_rvrsd=reversed_word+c+order_word_rvrsd
                order_rvrsd=original_word+c+order_rvrsd
                word_rvrsd=word_rvrsd+reversed_word+c
                original_word=''
                reversed_word=''
            indx+=1
        except IndexError:
            c=' '
            order_word_rvrsd=reversed_word+c+order_word_rvrsd
            order_rvrsd=original_word+c+order_rvrsd
            word_rvrsd=word_rvrsd+reversed_word
            break
    print(order_word_rvrsd,order_rvrsd,word_rvrsd,sep='\n')
```

But I found below smaller function from someone which does the same thing , but split the input string to list of words and iterate through it multiple times:

```
def reverseStr(s: str):
  splitted_s = s.split(" ")
  l = len(splitted_s)
  out1 = ""
  out2 = ""
  out3 = ""
  for i in range(1, l+1):
    out1 += splitted_s[-i][::-1] + " "
  for i in range(1, l+1):
    out2 += splitted_s[-i] + " "
  for i in range(l):
    out3 += splitted_s[i][::-1] + " "
  print(out1,out2,out3,sep='\n')
```

As per time complexity analysis my approach with single loop  should be of O(n) complexity since it iterates through string characters only once. While the second function does it multiple time. But surprisingly with bigger strings , second function is running faster than first one of mine.
[image]

Is this because  string iteration with single loop is slower compared to iteration of list of words created from string.split() with multiple loops?

Any help to understand is highly appreciated

Comment: For loops are 6 times faster than while loop, as stated [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/python-loops-performance-compared-the-fastest-is-b4638744a1ff)

Answer (score 3):

I did some rough calculations.

```
inp_str = ' '.join([''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 4)) for indx in range(10000)])
```

The `inp_str` string has a length of `10000 * 5 = 50000` characters and a space every `4` characters (`10000` *words*).

The loop in the `reverse_str` function:

```
indx = 0

while True:
    try:
        # ...
        indx += 1
    except IndexError:
        # ...
        break
```

is executed `50000` times. It means an input of `10000` space-chars and `40000` letters/numbers.

- For every non-space character there are `2` assignments and `2` concatenations

  ```
  original_word += c
  reversed_word = c + reversed_word
  ```
- for space characters there are, at least, `3` assignments and `6` concatenations

  ```
  order_word_rvrsd = reversed_word + c + order_word_rvrsd
  order_rvrsd = original_word + c + order_rvrsd
  word_rvrsd = word_rvrsd + reversed_word + c
  ```

The total is: `40000 * 2 + 10000 *3 = 110000` assignments and `40000 * 2 + 10000 * 6 = 140000` concatenations.

---

The `reverseStr` function has three loops each working on (more or less) `10000` words.

- The first loop (`for i in range(1, l+1):`) is executed `10000` times (`1` assignment and `2` concatenations);
- the second loop (`for i in range(1, l+1):`) is executed `10000` times (`1` assignment and `2` concatenations);
- the last loop  is executed `10000` times (`1` assignment and `2` concatenations);

So the total is: `30000` assignments and `60000` concatenations.

The difference is enough to compensate for the initial word-splitting (it probably, roughly requires `10000` assignments).

---

The performance difference increases with the average length of a word in the input string.

Comment: I understood. Somehow I was completely ignoring the concatenation part. Since strings are immutable, every concatenation will copy entire string again. And I found this interesting article on string concatenation in python : https://python.plainenglish.io/concatenating-strings-efficiently-in-python-9bfc8e8d6f6e where it clearly explains how costly the concatenation using '+' symbol is

Comment: What is the efficient way to optimize this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: You could try changing `out1`, `out2`, `out3` into lists and using the `append` function instead of  `+=`. Possibly, if you need a string, add a final `out1s = " ".join(out1)`